# How to sign a transaction using javascript

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, javascript

I know that it is possible to create an unsigned transaction using the wallet RPC (with the command `transfer`). Is it possible to sign this transaction with just javascript (without using the wallet RPC)? For example using the libsodium library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sign this transaction with just javascript (without using the wallet RPC)? For example using the libsodium library?

Not with libsodium, but with [monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript) it's possible.

See: [monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/master/docs/developer_guide/view_only_offline.md](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/master/docs/developer_guide/view_only_offline.md)

> ```
> // create offline wallet
> let offlineWallet = await monerojs.createWalletFull({...});
> ...
> // sign tx using offline wallet
> let signedTxHex = await offlineWallet.signTxs(unsignedTx.getTxSet().getUnsignedTxHex());
> ```

[`monerojs.createWalletFull`](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/master/docs/developer_guide/creating_wallets.md#webassembly-wallet) does not need RPC access.